# Updating records in a specific order

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update all records in my table. As I read through the records I need to update a column in the current record with a value from the NEXT record in the set. The catch is the updates need to be done in a specified order.

I was thinking of something like this ...

```
Update t1
Set col1 = (select LEAD(col2,1) OVER (ORDER BY col3, col4, col5)
            from t1);
```

This doesn't compile but you see what I'm driving at ... any ideas ?

... update

This peice does run successfully but writes only NULLS

```
Update t1 A
Set t1.col1 = (select LEAD(col2,1) OVER (ORDER BY col3, col4, col5)
           from t1 B
           where A.col3 = B.col3 AND
                 A.col4 = B.col4 AND
                 A.col5 = B.col5);
```

Comment: What do you mean "the updates need to be done in a specified order"?  Are you trying to control the order in which the SQL statement actually changes various blocks?  Or are you just saying that the `LEAD` function needs a specified `ORDER BY` clause in order to find the correct "next record"?

Comment: @danihp: no need for a temp table.

Comment: @JustinCave - I need the LEAD function to return a value from the loggically correct NEXT record. These are records from the same table so the keys used to return the NEXT record needs to be the same keys used to perform the Update statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
merge into t1
using
(
   select rowid as rid, 
          LEAD(col2,1) OVER (ORDER BY col3, col4, col5) as ld
   from t1
) lv on ( lv.rid = t1.rowid )
when matched then 
  update set col1 = lv.ld;
```

Not 100% sure if I got the syntax completely right, but as you didn't supply any testdata, I'll leave potential syntax errors for you to fix.

You can also replace the usage of `rowid` with the real primary key columns of your table.

Comment: +1, but ORA-00969: missing ON keyword without brackets.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/31821/9/1

Comment: awesome, thank you ! I don't know why my thought process didn't head toward the merge. It makes perfect sense in hind sight.

Comment: btw and fyi, this statement ran in 187msecs (1800 records) where my previous attempts to write this with cursors and for loops ran in 3 seconds. So without a doubt, the merge is the way to go. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use cursor? You can use update within a cursor with specified order.

Comment: i was able to accomplish it with a cursor and a whole bunch of for loops but I'm trying to write it as effeciently as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `with` statement:

```
with toupdate as (
    select t1.*,
           lead(col2, 1) over (order by col3, col4, col5) as nextval
    from t1
)
Update toupdate
    Set col1 = nextval
```

By the way, this does not guarantee the *ordering* of the updates.  However, col2 is not mentioned in the partitioning clause so it should do the right thing.

The above syntax works in SQL Server, but not Oracle.  The original question did not specify the database (and `lead` is a valid function in SQL Server 2012).  It seems the `merge` statement is the way to get the values in the subquery.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . No, this will update col1 with the value of col2 in the "next" record, where "next" is defined by the ordering of col3, col4, and col5.  It would only give them all the same value if col2 always contained the same value.